# Paginating with php/postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

i'm trying to create paging pages but i have got stuck here:

```
<?php  
    global $limit, $sql, $url, $pagesize, $pagecount, $absolutepage, $recordcount;  

    // Configuration...  
    $db = pg_Connect("dbname=Test user=postgres password=1111");

// If current page number, use it 
// if not, set one! 

if(!isset($_GET['page'])){ 
$page = 1; 
} else { 
$page = $_GET['page']; 
} 

// Define the number of results per page 
$max_results = 10; 

// Figure out the limit for the query based 
// on the current page number. 
$from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results); 

// Perform MySQL query on only the current page number's results 

$sql = pg_query("SELECT * FROM import.mock_data LIMIT $from OFFSET $max_results"); //LIMIT $pagesize OFFSET $offset

while($row = pg_fetch_array($sql)){ 
// Build your formatted results here. 
echo $row['first_name']."<br />"; 
} 

// Figure out the total number of results in DB: 
$total_results = pg_result(pg_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM import.mock_data"),0); 

// Figure out the total number of pages. Always round up using ceil() 
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $max_results); 

// Build Page Number Hyperlinks 
echo "<center>Selecione uma página<br />"; 

// Build Previous Link 
if($page > 1){ 
$prev = ($page - 1); 
echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=$prev\"><<Previous</a>&nbsp;"; 
} 

for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++){ 
if(($page) == $i){ 
echo "$i&nbsp;"; 
} else { 
echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=$i\">$i</a>&nbsp;"; 
} 
} 

// Build Next Link 
if($page < $total_pages){ 
$next = ($page + 1); 
echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=$next\">Next>></a>"; 
} 
echo "</center>"; 
?>
```

At this time i have this problems:
1- do not shows nothing at the beggining, just shows at the page 2 and on ...
2 - it just not pagionate but add the next ten records of the page 3 to the previous 10 records from the page 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the first `SELECT` query,

```
$sql = pg_query("SELECT * FROM import.mock_data LIMIT $from OFFSET $max_results");
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

With the current logic when you hop from page to page, your `OFFSET` would be same and the `LIMIT` would be getting increased from 0, 10, 20 and so on. Whereas in reality it should be the other way around. So your `SELECT` query should be like this:

```
$sql = pg_query("SELECT * FROM import.mock_data LIMIT $max_results OFFSET $from");
```

Comment: Thank you :) That was shocking for me. I need more carefully to examine the code.

Comment: @Hristian You're welcome! :-) Glad I could help. *Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

You got too many errors.

first you have to calculate offset like this

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
    $from = $max_results * $page ;
}
else 
{
            $page = 0;
            $from = 0;
}
```

Please follow this link
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm

Comment: There's no issue with the `OFFSET` here. OP has already calculated `OFFSET` in the following way, `$from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results); `